# Homogeneous pseudoscalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I'm reading about pseudoscalar inflation. I have a basic question. How can a pseudoscalar field be homogeneous in space? Since it should change sign under space inversion, seems to me the only way to be homogeneous in space is for it to be zero.

I'm referring to the fact that the inflaton field is assumed to be homogeneous (independent of space) but only a function of time $\phi(\textbf{x},t)=\phi(t)$. If this is the case, under $\textbf{r}\to -\textbf{r}$, apparently $\phi(t)\to \phi(t)$. But a pseudoscalar field behaves as $\phi\to -\phi$ under $\textbf{r}\to -\textbf{r}$.

I would appreciate it if this could be clarified.

Comment: Are you mixing up *homogeneous* and *isotropic*? To be *homogeneous* just means the field has the same value everywhere and doesn't imply anything about its behaviour under a parity inversion.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field. But I think $\phi(\textbf{x},t)=\phi(t)+\varphi(\textbf{x},t)$ where $\varphi(\textbf{x},t)$ denotes the space-time dependent fluctuations about the background $\phi(t)$. Maybe someone else can elaborate and correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your analysis is that it's not independent of the choice of origin.

A better way to think of this, perhaps, is that an observer using a right-handed coordinate system would observe the field to have the value $\phi(t)$ everywhere, while an observer using a left-handed coordinate system would observe $\phi'(t) = -\phi(t)$ everywhere.

For an argument that this must be possible, remember that the process for absorption of stopped negative pions (which are pseudoscalar particles) in matter involves the pions entering an $s$-wave orbital around a nucleus.